# How to re use the JTables

Tags: java, swing, jtable, defaulttablemodel

```
    import java.io.*;
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.event.*;
    import javax.swing.*;
    import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
    import java.awt.Color.*;
    import java.util.Date;
    import java.sql.*;
    import java.util.*;
    import java.text.DateFormat;
    import java.util.Timer;
    import java.util.TimerTask;
    import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
    import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
    import javax.swing.text.AttributeSet;
    import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;
    import javax.swing.text.AbstractDocument;
    import javax.swing.text.DocumentFilter;
    import javax.swing.text.DocumentFilter.FilterBypass;

    class CTS extends JFrame implements ActionListener
    {
    JLabel l,l1,l2,l3,l4,l5,l6,l7,l8,l9,l10,l11,l12,l13,l14,l15,l16,l17,l18,l19,l20,l21,l22,l23;
    JButton b1,b2,b3,b4,b5,b6,b7,b8,b9;
    JTextField t1,t2,t3,t4,t5,t6,t7,t8,t9,t10,t11,t12,t13,t14,t15;
    JPanel p1=new JPanel();
    JPanel p2=new JPanel();
    JPanel pBook = new JPanel();
    JComboBox cb1,cb2,cb3;
    JTextArea j1 = new JTextArea();
    JRadioButton rb1,rb2;
    JTable table = new JTable();
    JTable table1 = new JTable();
    int i,j,srcount;
    ButtonGroup bgrp = new ButtonGroup();
    String AgentID,sdfdate,from,to,customer;
    SimpleDateFormat sdf;
    Date date;
    Connection con;
    PreparedStatement pstmt;
    private DefaultTableModel dtm = new DefaultTableModel(0,0);
    Statement stmt;
    ResultSet rs;
    Dimension screen= Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    int total,netpay,balance;
    String s,bal,net;

    CTS()
    {
    super("Momin Traders");

    date= Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
    sdf= new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    sdfdate=sdf.format(date);

    date= Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
    sdf= new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    from=sdf.format(date);

    date= Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
    sdf= new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    to=sdf.format(date);

    p1.setLayout(null);
    p2.setLayout(null);
    p1.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(210, 210, 210));
    p1.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder());
    p2.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 226, 226));
    p2.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder());
    p2.setBounds(10,150,1335,380);

    try
            {
                // Load the Driver
                Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
                con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:MominDB","","");
                pstmt=con.prepareStatement("select * from CTS where Date=?");
                pstmt.setString(1,sdfdate);
                rs=pstmt.executeQuery();            

                int i=0;

    while(rs.next())
    {

    String s= rs.getString("SR#");
    int j = Integer.parseInt(s);

      if(i<j)
        i=j;
        System.out.println("i="+i);


    }

    srcount=i+1;
    }


        catch(Exception e)
        {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

    l=new JLabel(new ImageIcon("images/bg.jpg"));
    l.setBounds(0,0,screen.width,screen.height);    
    l1=new JLabel("Name");
    t1=new JTextField();
    l1.setBounds(10,70,70,80);
    t1.setBounds(45,100,100,20);

    l2=new JLabel("Description");
    t2=new JTextField();
    l2.setBounds(145,70,80,80);
    t2.setBounds(210,100,100,20);

    l3=new JLabel("Customer Search");
    l3.setBounds(300,30,130,20);
    t3=new JTextField();
    t3.setBounds(410,25,190,30);

    l4=new JLabel("From Date");
    l4.setBounds(620,30,90,20);
    t4=new JTextField();
    t4.setBounds(680,30,90,20);

    l11=new JLabel("To Date");
    l11.setBounds(790,30,90,20);
    t11=new JTextField();
    t11.setBounds(840,30,90,20);

    b5=new JButton("Search");
    b5.setBounds(950,25,80,30);
    b5.addActionListener(this);


    l5=new JLabel("Quantity");
    t5=new JTextField();
    l5.setBounds(315,70,60,80);
    t5.setBounds(365,100,100,20);

    l6=new JLabel("Weight");
    t6=new JTextField();
    l6.setBounds(475,70,60,80);
    t6.setBounds(520,100,100,20);


    l8=new JLabel("Rate");
    t7=new JTextField();
    l8.setBounds(625,70,60,80);
    t7.setBounds(655,100,100,20);


    l9=new JLabel("Total");
    t8=new JTextField();
    l9.setBounds(760,70,60,80);
    t8.setBounds(790,100,100,20);


    l10=new JLabel("Balance");
    t9=new JTextField();
    l10.setBounds(890,70,60,80);
    t9.setBounds(940,100,100,20);

    l14=new JLabel("Paid");
    t14=new JTextField();
    l14.setBounds(1040,70,60,80);
    t14.setBounds(1070,100,100,20);

    l15=new JLabel("Net Pay");
    t15=new JTextField();
    l15.setBounds(1170,70,60,80);
    t15.setBounds(1220,100,100,20);

    /////////////////////////////////////////////
    l16=new JLabel("Total");
    l16.setBounds(1110,530,60,80);

    l17=new JLabel("Balance");
    l17.setBounds(1110,550,60,80);

    l18=new JLabel("Net Pay");
    l18.setBounds(1110,570,60,80);


    l22=new JLabel("Firm Name |");
    l22.setBounds(10,0,90,80);

    l23=new JLabel("Momin Traders");
    l23.setBounds(90,0,130,80);


    b1=new JButton("Save");
    b1.setBounds(1240,120,80,30);


    b2=new JButton(new ImageIcon("Lg.jpg"));
    b2.setBounds(1260,10,50,50);
    b2.addActionListener(this);

    b3=new JButton(new ImageIcon("cp.jpg"));
    b3.setBounds(1180,10,50,50);
    b3.addActionListener(this);

    b4=new JButton(new ImageIcon("add.jpg"));
    b4.setBounds(1100,10,50,50);
    b4.addActionListener(this);

    b7=new JButton("Generate Invoice");
    b7.setBounds(620,570,190,40);
    b7.addActionListener(this);

    b8=new JButton("Generate Statement");
    b8.setBounds(840,570,190,40);
    b8.addActionListener(this);

    b9=new JButton("Reset");
    b9.setBounds(840,620,100,40);
    b9.addActionListener(this);

    rb1= new JRadioButton("Daily");
    rb1.setBounds(10,540,80,30);

    rb2= new JRadioButton("Weekly / Monthly");
    rb2.setBounds(10,570,170,30);
    b1.addActionListener(this);
    rb1.addActionListener(this);
    rb2.addActionListener(this);

    l19=new JLabel();
    l19.setBounds(1160,530,60,80);

    l20=new JLabel();
    l20.setBounds(1160,550,60,80);

    l21=new JLabel();
    l21.setBounds(1160,570,60,80);


    l12=new JLabel("From");
    t12=new JTextField(20);
    l12.setBounds(200,570,70,20);
    t12.setBounds(240,570,70,20);

    l13=new JLabel("To");
    t13=new JTextField(20);
    l13.setBounds(320,570,70,20);
    t13.setBounds(340,570,70,20);

    b6=new JButton("Search");
    b6.setBounds(420,570,100,20);
    b6.addActionListener(this);


    try
            {
                // Load the Driver
                Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
                con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:MominDB","","");


            }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    p1.add(l16);
    p1.add(l17);
    p1.add(l18);    
    p1.add(b7);
    p1.add(b8);
    p1.add(b5);
    p1.add(p2);
    p1.add(b1);
    p1.add(rb1);
    p1.add(rb2);
    p1.add(b2);
    p1.add(b3);
    p1.add(b4);
    add(l);
    add(p1);
    p1.add(l22);
    p1.add(l1);
    p1.add(t1);
    p1.add(l2);
    p1.add(t2);
    p1.add(l3);
    p1.add(t3);
    p1.add(l4);
    p1.add(t4);
    p1.add(l5);
    p1.add(t5);
    p1.add(l6);
    p1.add(t6);
    p1.add(t7);
    p1.add(l8);
    p1.add(t8);
    p1.add(l9);
    p1.add(l11);
    p1.add(t11);
    p1.add(l10);
    p1.add(t9);
    p1.add(rb1);
    bgrp.add(rb1);
    bgrp.add(rb2);
    p1.add(b9);
    rb1.enable(true);
    p1.add(t12);
    p1.add(l12);
    p1.add(l13);
    p1.add(t13);
    l12.setVisible(false);
    t12.setVisible(false);
    t13.setVisible(false);
    l13.setVisible(false);
    b6.setVisible(false);
    customer=t3.getText();
    p1.add(b6);
    p1.add(l23);
    p1.add(l14);
    p1.add(l15);
    p1.add(t14);
    p1.add(t15);
    p1.add(l19);
    p1.add(l20);
    p1.add(l21);

    DocumentFilter df=new DocumentFilter()
    {
     public void insertString(FilterBypass fb, int i, String string, AttributeSet as) throws BadLocationException
    { 
     if(isDigit(string))
      { 
        super.insertString(fb,i,string,as);
        calc();
     }
    }

     public void remove(FilterBypass fb, int i, int i1) throws BadLocationException
    {
     super.remove(fb,i,i1);
     calc();
    }

     public void replace(FilterBypass fb, int i, int i1, String string, AttributeSet as) throws BadLocationException
    {
     if(isDigit(string))
      {
       super.replace(fb,i,i1,string,as);
       calc();
      }
    }

     private boolean isDigit(String string)
    { 
     for(int n=0; n < string.length(); n++)
     {
      char c = string.charAt(n); //get a single character string
       //System.out.println(c);
       if(!Character.isDigit(c))
       {
        //if it is an alpabetical charcater or white space
        return true;
       }
      }
       return true;
    }

    void calc()
    {
     double total;
     double netpay;
     double quantity=0.0;
     double weight=0.0;
     double rate=0.0;
     double bal=0.0;
     double paid=0.0;
      if(!t5.getText().isEmpty())
     {
      quantity=Double.parseDouble(t5.getText()); //we must add this
     }
      if(!t6.getText().isEmpty())
      {
      weight=Double.parseDouble(t6.getText()); //we must add this
      }
      if(!t7.getText().isEmpty())
      {
       rate=Double.parseDouble(t7.getText());
      }
       total=weight*rate;
      t8.setText(String.valueOf(total));

      if(!t9.getText().isEmpty())
      {
       bal=Double.parseDouble(t9.getText());
      }
      if(!t14.getText().isEmpty())
     {
      paid=Integer.parseInt(t14.getText()); //we must add this
     }
      netpay=total+bal-paid;
      t15.setText(String.valueOf(netpay));
    }

    };


    ((AbstractDocument)(t7.getDocument())).setDocumentFilter(df);
    ((AbstractDocument)(t5.getDocument())).setDocumentFilter(df);
    ((AbstractDocument)(t6.getDocument())).setDocumentFilter(df);
    ((AbstractDocument)(t14.getDocument())).setDocumentFilter(df);
    ((AbstractDocument)(t9.getDocument())).setDocumentFilter(df);


    pBook.setLayout (null);
    setSize(screen);
    setVisible(true);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


    DefaultTableModel dtm = new DefaultTableModel(new Object[]{"SR#", "Date", "Name", "Description", "Quantity", "Weight", "Rate", "Total", "Balance","Paid","Net Pay"},0);

    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
    {

    DefaultTableModel dtm = new DefaultTableModel(new Object[]{"SR#", "Date", "Name", "Description", "Quantity", "Weight", "Rate", "Total", "Balance","Paid","Net Pay"},0);                     
        table= new JTable(dtm);
        table.setModel(dtm); 
        JScrollPane scroller = new JScrollPane(table);
        table.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255,226,226));
        scroller.setBounds(0,0,1335,380);
        p2.add(scroller);
        dtm.setRowCount(0);
        /*dtm.addRow(new Object[]{rs.getString(1),rs.getString(2),rs.getString(3),rs.getString(4),rs.getString(5),rs.getString(6),rs.getString(7),rs.getString(8),rs.getString(9),rs.getString(10),rs.getString(11)});*/

    if(ae.getSource()==b9)
    {
    dtm.setRowCount(0);
    }


    if(ae.getSource()==b1)
    {
    try{
    if(t1.getText().equals("")||t2.getText().equals("")||t6.getText().equals("")||t7.getText().equals("")||t8.getText().equals("")||t9.getText().equals(""))
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(CTS.this,"Please enter the data in all the fields...","Error Message..",JOptionPane.OK_OPTION);
            else {
                    // Establish the connection
                   Connection con =DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:MominDB","","");
                    System.out.println("Connection Established of create");

                    PreparedStatement pstmt=con.prepareStatement("insert into CTS values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
                    pstmt.setString(1,String.valueOf(srcount));
                    pstmt.setString(2,sdfdate);
                    pstmt.setString(3,t1.getText());
                    pstmt.setString(4,t2.getText());
                    pstmt.setString(5,t5.getText());
                    pstmt.setString(6,t6.getText());
                    pstmt.setString(7,t7.getText());
                    pstmt.setString(8,t8.getText());
                    pstmt.setString(9,t9.getText());
                    pstmt.setString(10,t14.getText());
                    pstmt.setString(11,t15.getText());


                                 pstmt.executeUpdate();
                                  srcount++;

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        try{

                    stmt = con.createStatement();
                    rs=stmt.executeQuery("select * from CTS where Date='"+sdfdate+"' ");
                                while(rs.next())
                                {
                            dtm.addRow(new Object[]{rs.getString(1),rs.getString(2),rs.getString(3),rs.getString(4),rs.getString(5),rs.getString(6),rs.getString(7),rs.getString(8),rs.getString(9),rs.getString(10),rs.getString(11)});
                                System.out.println("Working rb1");
                                }
                                t1.setText("");t2.setText("");t3.setText("");t5.setText("");t6.setText("");t7.setText("");t8.setText("");
                                t9.setText("");t14.setText("");t15.setText("");
                                }
                                    catch(Exception e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                                    }

                            }         
                            }   
            catch(Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(CTS.this,"Record is not created, \n  please try again or check your Database connection ","Error Message...",JOptionPane.OK_OPTION);
                }
    }






    /*====================================================================*/
    if(ae.getSource()==b2)
    {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(CTS.this,"System is shutting down.....\nHave a nice day","System Shuting down",JOptionPane.OK_OPTION);
    System.exit(0);
    }
    if(ae.getSource()==b3)
    {
    new cpass().setVisible(true);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(MainMenu.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    }
        if(ae.getSource()==b5)

        if(t3.getText().equals("")||t4.getText().equals("")||t11.getText().equals(""))
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(CTS.this,"Please enter the data in all the fields...","Error Message..",JOptionPane.OK_OPTION);
        else{

        try{
            dtm.setRowCount(0);
            stmt = con.createStatement();
        rs=stmt.executeQuery("select * from CTS where name='"+t3.getText()+"' and Date BETWEEN '"+t4.getText()+"' and '"+t11.getText()+"'");        
        while(rs.next())
        {


        dtm.addRow(new Object[]{rs.getString(1),rs.getString(2),rs.getString(3),rs.getString(4),rs.getString(5),rs.getString(6),rs.getString(7),rs.getString(8),rs.getString(9),rs.getString(10),rs.getString(11)});



                                }
                                }
                                    catch(Exception e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
        try{
        rs=stmt.executeQuery("select total from CTS where name='"+t3.getText()+"' and Date BETWEEN '"+t4.getText()+"' and '"+t11.getText()+"'");
        while(rs.next())
        {
        total+=rs.getInt(1);
        }

        System.out.println(total);

        s= String.valueOf(total);

        l19.setText(s);
        total=0;

        rs=stmt.executeQuery("select balance from CTS where name='"+t3.getText()+"' and Date BETWEEN '"+t4.getText()+"' and '"+t11.getText()+"'");
        while(rs.next())
        {
        balance+=rs.getInt(1);

        }
        System.out.println(balance);

        bal= String.valueOf(balance);

        l20.setText(bal);
        balance=0;

        rs=stmt.executeQuery("select netpay from CTS where name='"+t3.getText()+"' and Date BETWEEN '"+t4.getText()+"' and '"+t11.getText()+"'");
        while(rs.next())
        {
        netpay+=rs.getInt(1);
        }
        System.out.println(netpay);

        net= String.valueOf(netpay);

        l21.setText(net);
        netpay=0;


        }

        catch(Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                        }


    }
    if(ae.getSource()==rb1)
    {
    dtm.setRowCount(0);
    try{    
        stmt = con.createStatement();
        rs=stmt.executeQuery("select * from CTS"); 


                    while(rs.next())
                    {

            dtm.addRow(new Object[]{rs.getString(1),rs.getString(2),rs.getString(3),rs.getString(4),rs.getString(5),rs.getString(6),rs.getString(7),rs.            getString(8),rs.getString(9),rs.getString(10),rs.getString(11)});
            System.out.println("Working rb1");

                    }

                    stmt = con.createStatement();
        rs=stmt.executeQuery("select sum(total) from CTS where Date='"+sdfdate+"' ");

        while(rs.next())
        {
        System.out.println("in side total");

        }
                    }
                        catch(Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                                try{
                rs=stmt.executeQuery("select total from CTS where Date='"+sdfdate+"' ");
                while(rs.next())
                {
                total+=rs.getInt(1);

                }

                System.out.println(total);

                s= String.valueOf(total);

                l19.setText(s);
                total=0;

                rs=stmt.executeQuery("select balance from CTS where Date='"+sdfdate+"' ");
                while(rs.next())
                {
                balance+=rs.getInt(1);

                }
                System.out.println(balance);

                bal= String.valueOf(balance);

                l20.setText(bal);
                balance=0;

                rs=stmt.executeQuery("select netpay from CTS where Date='"+sdfdate+"' ");
                while(rs.next())
                {
                netpay+=rs.getInt(1);
                }
                System.out.println(netpay);

                net= String.valueOf(netpay);

                l21.setText(net);
                netpay=0;

                }

                catch(Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                                }


    }

    if(ae.getSource()==b7)
    {
    new invoice();
    }
    if(ae.getSource()==b8)
    {
    new St();
    }

    if(ae.getSource()==rb2)
    {
    t12.setVisible(true);
    l12.setVisible(true);
    t13.setVisible(true);
    l13.setVisible(true);
    b6.setVisible(true);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(MainMenu.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    }

    if(ae.getSource()!=rb2 && ae.getSource()!=b6)
    {
    t12.setVisible(false);
    l12.setVisible(false);
    t13.setVisible(false);
    l13.setVisible(false);
    b6.setVisible(false);
    rb1.enable(true);
    }

    if(ae.getSource()==b6)
    {
    try{
                stmt = con.createStatement();
                rs=stmt.executeQuery("select * from CTS where Date BETWEEN '"+t12.getText()+"' and '"+t13.getText()+"'");

                            while(rs.next())
                            {
                            dtm.addRow(new Object[]{rs.getString(1),rs.getString(2),rs.getString(3),rs.getString(4),rs.getString(5),rs.getString(6),rs.getString(7),rs.getString(8),rs.getString(9),rs.getString(10),rs.getString(11)});

                                    System.out.println("Working rb2");

                            }

            }


    catch(Exception e)
    {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try{
                rs=stmt.executeQuery("select total from CTS where  Date BETWEEN '"+t12.getText()+"' and '"+t13.getText()+"'");
                while(rs.next())
                {
                total+=rs.getInt(1);

                }

                System.out.println(total);

                s= String.valueOf(total);

                l19.setText(s);
                total=0;

                rs=stmt.executeQuery("select balance from CTS where  Date BETWEEN '"+t12.getText()+"' and '"+t13.getText()+"'");
                while(rs.next())
                {
                balance+=rs.getInt(1);

                }
                System.out.println(balance);

                bal= String.valueOf(balance);

                l20.setText(bal);
                balance=0;

                rs=stmt.executeQuery("select netpay from CTS where  Date BETWEEN '"+t12.getText()+"' and '"+t13.getText()+"'");
                while(rs.next())
                {
                netpay+=rs.getInt(1);
                }
                System.out.println(netpay);

                net= String.valueOf(netpay);

                l21.setText(net);
                netpay=0;

                }
                catch(Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                                }

    }

    if(ae.getSource()==b4)
    {
    new Add().setVisible(true);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(MainMenu.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    }

    if(ae.getSource()==p1)
    {
    new MainMenu().setVisible(false);
    }

    }
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
    new CTS();

    }
    }
```

You need to do the following before you run the code to implement on your machine:

1. Set the system DSN with name MominDB.mdb (its an microsoft access file).
2. Fill up the table named as CTS ( table name is CTS) from where all the data is been fetched.
3. Fill up the table until you get the scroller down. (This is the main issue) Scroller is getting overlaped.

Comment: use same table..show us code for adding data to table

Comment: Okay! just a second I will edit my question

Comment: Fast Snail, I have edited my code please have a look and assist me on it, Please. This is the second method I also have tried with DefaultTableModel if you want I can show you that code as well. Please let me know.

Comment: first create jtable with column names then add rows .using `jtablemodel.addRow():`

Comment: I'll show you how I did that by using DefaultTableModel However, I need to create a new object every time that is nonsense thing that I am doing I wana get rid of that. I will show you the code and you tell me what is the alternate method for it

Comment: I have edited again by the method of DefaultTableModel, which is similar like what you have suggested, please have a look. On every new event I want to display a different data and want to clear the contents that were displayed on my previous event

Comment: row adding part is perfect only problem is your are creating a table and model every time ..you shouldn't add table creating code inside the button click method .create jtable and model just one time may be when gui start. and inside the button click event add rows to the existing table

Comment: Yeah I tried that however, the new event data is appended at the end of the old event data and both are displayed a the same time

Comment: before you add data use  `model.setRowCount(0);` to clear the table

Comment: I have tried that as well but not getting result, can you please give a demonstration by editing my code.

Comment: You're asking @FastSnail to create a [mcve] for you, but since he's a volunteer, and you're the one asking for help, it is much more appropriate for you to create and post your [mcve] first, and then allow him to modify it if need be, to help you out.

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels, If you able to understand my code then help me with this.

Comment: @Fast Snail, I have edited the code as per your input however, Its running but I am unable to see anything on my screen. Please help me

Comment: @Umair7: I'll better be able to understand things if you create and post your [mcve]. If you don't get a full answer soon, then you'll want to do this.

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels, My code is really big to post here and to read I totally understand what do you mean, however, I want to spend time in research then to create  Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. I will update my code for you for better understanding

Comment: I did not ask for your whole code, just enough to run and to show us your problem.

Comment: I have edited my code, I will try to post a code which even you can run and see on your machine. In the mean time please have a look on this code, and see if you can conclude something.

Comment: Also, the volunteers on this site always appreciate it if posters put in the effort to post **well-formatted code**, something that you haven't yet done. Please fix this, else you're only making it harder for folks to read and understand what you've posted.

Comment: Instead of pitching me on the format of the code I would rather appreciate the relevant conclusion to my question. Moreover, I don't think there is any problem in understanding the above code for a "Programmer".

Comment: Good, then since you're a "programmer", you've solved your problem, right?

Comment: I was here for help on my issue, since you are unable and I mean "UNABLE" to answer my question, you started with offending words. You are just replying without any logical reason behind your words. if you have something of note then only speak else consider this experience as your failure.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

1. Make your model (`dtm`) a member field.
2. Remove `setModel` and `scroller.add` calls in the action listener.
3. Before your `while` loop - reset the data model to empty. You can call `setRowCount(0)` or `getDataVector().clear()`.

Then see whether it works. Please post formatted code, so that we can read it well.

Comment: Sir, I have edited my code, please see and suggest If I have left any thing

Comment: @ KDM, If I am adding the scroller, table and setModel in a constructor (As I have done in above example) then my scroller does not work.

Comment: @Umair7 I don't see the modifications. Anyhow, if it works for you - it is correct :)

Comment: If I dont create a new object for every listener I am unable to see anything on panel however, sql query still running, And if I create the objects of table and scroller in constructor, my scroller gets freezed. I am new to stack overflow I dont have much reputations to post screenshots here. Please help...